# How to detect if window has focus in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, window

I know these two methods on how to check if `window` has `focus` or not.

```js
if (document.hasFocus()) {
  // Window has focus
} else {
  // Window does not have focus
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  // Window has focus
})
window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  // Window does not have focus
})
```

**However I am not able to solve one problem:**

Whenever I open the console, the code shows that the page is not focused even though I am on that page. I am building a screen time calculator and this is causing issues.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: When you open console, the focus goes to the console the page loses focus, so its reporting correct.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Is there any way to detect if the document's console has focus? That would solve the problem.

Comment: @KeshavBajaj Can you elaborate on what actual problem you are trying to solve? Why does it matter that the window loses focus when console is clicked? Such details can help providing you a better suited answer.

Comment: @Ivar I have a timer that is incrementing while I am on my page, If the console is opened, the page loses focus and the timer stops. So, is there a way to keep the counter going on even while the console is opened and stop the timer if I go to another tab.

Comment: Maybe the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) could be of use here?

Comment: Running timers (setInterval, setTimeout) in the background is not good idea, there is no guarantee that the code inside timers will execute on time because browsers can throttle, pause those for performance reasons. Instead use real time like `performance.now()`

Comment: Or run them in a web worker